unable to delete a property (or appProperty) using php client in google drive object
Searching in the web and in Stack Overflow I didn't find post where the problem was solved
I've this code
        $params = array();
        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $file->setProperties("myProp"=>null);
        $response = $driveService->files->update($fileid,$file,$params);

and has no effect... the property mantains its original value (set with the same method)

In this case, how about using Google_Model::NULL_VALUE? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
From:
$file->setProperties("myProp"=>null);

To:
For properties
$file->setProperties(['myProp'=>Google_Model::NULL_VALUE]);

For appProperties
$file->setAppProperties(['myProp'=>Google_Model::NULL_VALUE]);


When I tested this, I confirmed that properties (or appProperties) are removed.

References:

REST Resource: files
Google_Model


It worked! Thanks :) I searched for a couple of days here and in the web, without a solution!

@jthomas Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
